# Asterisk, generete unique identifier per call

Tags: asterisk

I was trying to get a unique identifier for each call that is not the caller phone number (CALLERID(num)) + some kind of timestamp. 
Is there a variable a uniquely identifies a call in asterisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk already have that variable:

```
CDR(uniqueid)
```

have unique value for each call.

Also if you are using sip, each sip have SIPCALLID variable, which is unique per call-leg.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/chan_sip+Channel+Variables

If you need more unique values - you can add more variables using function RANDOM.

Comment: UNIQUEID is obsolete. better use same from CDR.

Comment: I saw they were returning the same result, great having this heads up. Since when is it obsolete?

Comment: It is very old variable. In newer version most of functions like that moved to CDR and CHANNEL. I can't say when it will be removed, but that have non-zero chance. So better use CDR